# How to check if java.nio.file.Path is from the default file system?

Tags: java, file, java-8, nio2

What's the easiest way to check if a `java.nio.file.Path` is a path from the default file system?

I'm working with an older API that still uses `java.io.File` but also allows to pass an `java.net.URL`.

I've come up with two possible solutions but they don't seem clean to me:

1. Catching `UnsupportedOperationException` when calling `Path.toFile()` but then I would use exceptions for the normal program flow.
2. Call `Path.toUri()` and check if the scheme is `"file"` or `null`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pathInstance.getFileSystem().equals(FileSystems.getDefault())
```

Comment: I think, a reference comparison (`==`) is sufficient here, especially, as it would actually counteract the intention, if a file system had a contradicting `equals` implementation.